# Trying to code a calculator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calculator

I've made a calculator for a school assignment only after hours of typing and trying to fix my code. It still is not working and I was hoping someone could find my mistakes.

```js
function myStory() {
  window.alert ("Very doge");
}

// Als de pagina laadt: laad de query

$(document).ready(function(){
  // Onthoud de input van de gebruiker om later te gebruiken
  var inputs=[""];

  // Onthoud de input van de gebruikers die eerst word ingetypt.
  var totalString;

  // Operator array voor validatie geheugen
  var operators1 = ["Mc", "M+", "M-", "MR"];

  // Operator array voor validatie zonder '.' Zo kan er niet bijv. 2x ++
  // worden ingevuld
  var operators2 = ["+", "-", "/", "X", "+/-"];

  // Operators arrat voor validatie met de '.'
  var operators3 = ["."];

  // Nummers voor validatie
  var numbers = [0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];


  //Functie om alles te updaten
  // ALS er een punt in zit, dan wordt er gekeken of het er maar 1 is en niet
  // meerdere, anders krijg je de error: Duplicate
  function getValue(input){
    if(operators3.includes(inputs[inputs.length-1]) === true && input === "."){
      window.alert("Duplicate '.' ");
    }
    else if (inputs.length === 1 && operators2.includes(input) === false){
      inputs.push(input);
    }
    else if(operators2.includes(inputs[inputs.length-1]) === false){
      inputs.push(input);
    }
    else if (numbers.includes(Number(input))){
      inputs.push(input);
    }
    update();
  }

  //Functie om de display te updaten
  function update(){
    totalString = inputs.join("");
    $("#display").html(totalString);
    console.log(inputs);
  }

  //Functie om het totaal te berekenen bijv. 8+6-4 wordt ingevuld
  // Dit wordt dan in 1x berekend. Het wordt zegmaar ge-evalueerd
  function getTotal(){
    totalString = inputs.join("");
    $("#display").html(eval(totalString));
  }

  //Wanneer er op een button wordt geklikt, voer dan de functie uit.
  $("input").on("click", function(){
    if (this.id === "C"){
      inputs=[""];
      update();
    }
    else if (this.id === "="){
      getTotal();
    }
    else {
      if(inputs[inputs.length-1].indexOf("+", "-", "/", "X", "+/-") === -1){
        getValue(this.id);
      }
      else {
        getValue(this.id);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 20px 40px 45px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

form[name="calculator"] {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#answer {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 320px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#display {
  padding-left: 300px;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.line {
  width: 320px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
}

input[type="button"] {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #525252;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

input[type="button"]:hover {
  border: none;
  color: #f67474;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input.numbers {
  color: #9d9d9d;
}

input.red {
  color: #f67474;
}

input.red:hover {
  color: #525252;
}

/* Memes */
p {
  color: #9d9d9d;
  float: left;
}

input.m1 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px !important;
  background-color: inherit;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;
}

input.m2 {
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px !important;
  background-color: inherit;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;
}

input.m3 {
  margin-left: 1100px;
  margin-top: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px !important;
  background-color: inherit;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;
}

input.m4 {
  margin-left: 1000px;
  margin-top: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px !important;
  background-color: inherit;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;
}

input.m5 {
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 450px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px !important;
  background-color: inherit;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;
}

input.m6 {
  margin-left: 1200px;
  margin-top: 340px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px !important;
  background-color: inherit;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;
}

input.m7 {
  margin-left: 1100px;
  margin-top: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px !important;
  background-color: inherit;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;
}

input.m8 {
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px !important;
  background-color: inherit;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;
}


/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes rainbow{
 20%{color: red;}
 40%{color: purple;}
 60%{color: green;}
 80%{color: blue;}
 100%{color: orange;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="javascriptcalc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Clean Calculator</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- many memes -->


    <input class="m1" type="button" value="such wow" onclick="myStory()">
    <input class="m2" type="button" value="many calculate" onclick="myStory()">
    <input class="m3" type="button" value="very machine" onclick="myStory()">
    <input class="m4" type="button" value="much javascript" onclick="myStory()">
    <input class="m5" type="button" value="such root" onclick="myStory()">
    <input class="m6" type="button" value="many squares" onclick="myStory()">
    <input class="m7" type="button" value="very numbers" onclick="myStory()">
    <input class="m8" type="button" value="much code" onclick="myStory()">


    <!-- Calculator -->

    <div id="container">

      <form name="calculator">
          <div id="answer">
            <span id="display">0</span>
          </div>
          </br>
          <div class="line"></div>

        <input type="button" id="MC" value="MC"/>
        <input type="button" id="M+" value="M+"/>
        <input type="button" id="M-" value="M-"/>
        <input type="button" id="MR" value="MR"/>
          </br>

        <input type="button" id="C" value="C"/>
        <input type="button" id="+/-" value="+/-"/>
        <input type="button" id="%" value="%"/>
        <input class="red" type="button" id="/" value="/"/>
          </br>

        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="7" value="7"/>
        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="8" value="8"/>
        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="9" value="9"/>
        <input class="red" type="button" id="X" value="X"/>
          </br>

        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="4" value="4"/>
        <input class="numbers" type="button"id="5"  value="5"/>
        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="6" value="6"/>
        <input class="red" type="button" id="-" value="-"/>
          </br>

        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="1" value="1"/>
        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="2" value="2"/>
        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="3" value="3"/>
        <input class="red" type="button" id="+" value="+"/>
          </br>

        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="00" value="00"/>
        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="0" value="0"/>
        <input type="button" id="," value=","/>
        <input class="red" type="button" id="=" value="="/>
          </br>

      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: please have a look here: [mcve]

Comment: whoa too much code. Just add the part where you are facing problem

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/68y2i74sPb2z5AVbbqyN?p=preview Have a look at the `html` file. You need to load jQuery before you load you calculator `script`. I found the issue just by inspecting your code. If you don't understand how to debug your code first, you will have trouble along the way learning JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing **jquery**. load using

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
function myStory() {
  window.alert ("Very doge");
}

// Als de pagina laadt: laad de query

$(document).ready(function(){
  // Onthoud de input van de gebruiker om later te gebruiken
  var inputs=[""];

  // Onthoud de input van de gebruikers die eerst word ingetypt.
  var totalString;

  // Operator array voor validatie geheugen
  var operators1 = ["Mc", "M+", "M-", "MR"];

  // Operator array voor validatie zonder '.' Zo kan er niet bijv. 2x ++
  // worden ingevuld
  var operators2 = ["+", "-", "/", "X", "+/-"];

  // Operators arrat voor validatie met de '.'
  var operators3 = ["."];

  // Nummers voor validatie
  var numbers = [0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];


  //Functie om alles te updaten
  // ALS er een punt in zit, dan wordt er gekeken of het er maar 1 is en niet
  // meerdere, anders krijg je de error: Duplicate
  function getValue(input){
    if(operators3.includes(inputs[inputs.length-1]) === true && input === "."){
      window.alert("Duplicate '.' ");
    }
    else if (inputs.length === 1 && operators2.includes(input) === false){
      inputs.push(input);
    }
    else if(operators2.includes(inputs[inputs.length-1]) === false){
      inputs.push(input);
    }
    else if (numbers.includes(Number(input))){
      inputs.push(input);
    }
    update();
  }

  //Functie om de display te updaten
  function update(){
    totalString = inputs.join("");
    $("#display").html(totalString);
    console.log(inputs);
  }

  //Functie om het totaal te berekenen bijv. 8+6-4 wordt ingevuld
  // Dit wordt dan in 1x berekend. Het wordt zegmaar ge-evalueerd
  function getTotal(){
    totalString = inputs.join("");
    $("#display").html(eval(totalString));
  }

  //Wanneer er op een button wordt geklikt, voer dan de functie uit.
  $("input").on("click", function(){
    if (this.id === "C"){
      inputs=[""];
      update();
    }
    else if (this.id === "="){
      getTotal();
    }
    else {
      if(inputs[inputs.length-1].indexOf("+", "-", "/", "X", "+/-") === -1){
        getValue(this.id);
      }
      else {
        getValue(this.id);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 20px 40px 45px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

form[name="calculator"] {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#answer {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 320px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#display {
  padding-left: 300px;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.line {
  width: 320px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
}

input[type="button"] {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #525252;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

input[type="button"]:hover {
  border: none;
  color: #f67474;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input.numbers {
  color: #9d9d9d;
}

input.red {
  color: #f67474;
}

input.red:hover {
  color: #525252;
}

/* Memes */
p {
  color: #9d9d9d;
  float: left;
}

input.m1 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px !important;
  background-color: inherit;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;
}

input.m2 {
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px !important;
  background-color: inherit;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;
}

input.m3 {
  margin-left: 1100px;
  margin-top: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px !important;
  background-color: inherit;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;
}

input.m4 {
  margin-left: 1000px;
  margin-top: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px !important;
  background-color: inherit;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;
}

input.m5 {
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 450px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px !important;
  background-color: inherit;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;
}

input.m6 {
  margin-left: 1200px;
  margin-top: 340px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px !important;
  background-color: inherit;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;
}

input.m7 {
  margin-left: 1100px;
  margin-top: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px !important;
  background-color: inherit;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;
}

input.m8 {
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px !important;
  background-color: inherit;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-animation: rainbow 2s infinite;
}


/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes rainbow{
 20%{color: red;}
 40%{color: purple;}
 60%{color: green;}
 80%{color: blue;}
 100%{color: orange;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascriptcalc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <title>Clean Calculator</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- many memes -->


    <input class="m1" type="button" value="such wow" onclick="myStory()">
    <input class="m2" type="button" value="many calculate" onclick="myStory()">
    <input class="m3" type="button" value="very machine" onclick="myStory()">
    <input class="m4" type="button" value="much javascript" onclick="myStory()">
    <input class="m5" type="button" value="such root" onclick="myStory()">
    <input class="m6" type="button" value="many squares" onclick="myStory()">
    <input class="m7" type="button" value="very numbers" onclick="myStory()">
    <input class="m8" type="button" value="much code" onclick="myStory()">


    <!-- Calculator -->

    <div id="container">

      <form name="calculator">
          <div id="answer">
            <span id="display">0</span>
          </div>
          </br>
          <div class="line"></div>

        <input type="button" id="MC" value="MC"/>
        <input type="button" id="M+" value="M+"/>
        <input type="button" id="M-" value="M-"/>
        <input type="button" id="MR" value="MR"/>
          </br>

        <input type="button" id="C" value="C"/>
        <input type="button" id="+/-" value="+/-"/>
        <input type="button" id="%" value="%"/>
        <input class="red" type="button" id="/" value="/"/>
          </br>

        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="7" value="7"/>
        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="8" value="8"/>
        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="9" value="9"/>
        <input class="red" type="button" id="X" value="X"/>
          </br>

        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="4" value="4"/>
        <input class="numbers" type="button"id="5"  value="5"/>
        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="6" value="6"/>
        <input class="red" type="button" id="-" value="-"/>
          </br>

        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="1" value="1"/>
        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="2" value="2"/>
        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="3" value="3"/>
        <input class="red" type="button" id="+" value="+"/>
          </br>

        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="00" value="00"/>
        <input class="numbers" type="button" id="0" value="0"/>
        <input type="button" id="," value=","/>
        <input class="red" type="button" id="=" value="="/>
          </br>

      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to load `jQuery` first before loading the `javascriptcalc.js` file.

Comment: This should be a comment or edit the question and update the snippet. but Not an answer.